# How to add jQuery UI to Rails with Require.js and backbone

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

I have used the `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` in the gem file, but am unsure how to get it working using require, as it modularizes the JS files, and backbone, as it adds the entire client side framework.

application.css (Rails):

```
 *= require bootstrap
 *= require jquery.ui.all
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
*/
```

application.js (Rails):

```
require([
 'APP'
], function(Application){
  Application.initialize(App.options);
});
```

movableObject.html (Backbone Template):

```
<div id="draggable" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
</div>
```

I have tried calling the function `$(function() {$( "#draggable" ).draggable();})` in various places (backbone view, higher in the application), but either get that jQuery isn't defined (too high in the application loading) or that the object doesn't have the function draggable() (leading me to believe that the JS for jQuery UI hasn't been loaded).

I also have `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.css` and `jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.css` in the stylesheets folder that I dled and put directly in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the requirejs.yml file :

```
modules:
  - name: 'backbone'
  - name: 'routers'

shim:
  'underscore':
    deps: ['jquery']
    exports: '_'
  'backbone':
    deps: ['underscore', 'jquery']
    exports: 'Backbone'
  'jquery-ui':
    deps: ['jquery']
    exports: '$'
```

To the JS file named in the `application.js` file, in this case `APP.js` because of `'APP'`:

```
//APP.js
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'backbone/routers/router',  
  'd3',
  'jquery-ui'
], function($, _, Backbone, Router, d3, $){
  var initialize = function(options){
    Router.initialize(options);
  }
  return {
    initialize: initialize
  };
});
```